# Nobody will end up dead

Tags: riddle, word

In this battle you are choosing
weapons hard or sharp or flat,
sometimes winning, sometimes losing,
otherwise a futile threat.
Despite the arms which you are using
nobody will end up dead,
for this fight is just amusing,
exists solely in your head.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surely it's

> A game of rock, paper, scissors.

In this battle you are choosing
weapons hard or sharp or flat,

> Hard - rock; sharp - scissors; flat - paper

sometimes winning, sometimes losing,
otherwise a futile threat.

> Three equally likely outcomes

Despite the arms which you are using
nobody will end up dead,

> Rarely does someone become Violent

for this fight is just amusing,
exists solely in your head.

Comment: That was fast, you rock.

Comment: Well *you* paper.

Answer (score 3):

> **Music**?

*In this battle you are choosing 

 weapons hard or sharp or flat,*

> Hard, sharp, and flat musical notes.

*sometimes winning, sometimes losing,*

> Going up and down in pitch?

*otherwise a futile threat.*

> Nobody is harmed.

*Despite the arms which you are using*

> You use your arms/hands to play the piano, the violin, and most other musical instruments.

*nobody will end up dead,*

> Obviously.

*for this fight is just amusing,*

> It amuses your audience.

*exists solely in your head.*

> That is, if you can play music without seeing the scores!